# How to Run two Python modules at the same time?

Tags: python

I have not been able to run two python modules at the same time. When I hit the run button it just run one module and I don´t know if there is a way to run both at the same time. I am using LiClipse.

This is the program of one module:

```
import asyncio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from alicat import FlowMeter



async def get(flowmeter):
        i=0
        while i<3:
            data2 = await flowmeter.get()
            plt.scatter(i,data2['mass_flow'],c='r')
            plt.pause(1)
            i=i+1
            print(data2)

async def main():
        plt.ion()
        flowmeter = FlowMeter("COM3:A")

        task = asyncio.create_task(get(flowmeter))
        await task

if __name__ == "__main__":
        asyncio.run(main())
```

and this is the code for the other module:

```
import nidaqmx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 
plt.ion()
 
i=0
 
with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
    task.ai_channels.add_ai_thrmcpl_chan("Dev1/ai0:2")
    while i<3:
        data = task.read(number_of_samples_per_channel=1)
        plt.scatter(i,data[0],c='r')
        plt.scatter(i,data[1],c='b')
        plt.scatter(i,data[2],c='y')
        plt.pause(1)
        i=i+1
        print (data)
```

I think the options would be:

1. Merge both codes into just one module, I tried that but it runs one and then proceeds with the other. It doesn´t run them simultaneously.
2. Run them using a third module that calls both modules but I am not sure if that´s even possible.

Comment: you dont have to merge the code, but it would be a good idea to move that code into functions that you can import and use.  Your current implementation relies on side effects, which is a bad thing. Well the first module looks already good, but the second one not.

Comment: By move the code into functions you mean use "def" to then call them? What does not look good on the second code? Thanks

Comment: @marsit, the first module is providing functions and will only run those if called directly `if _name__ == "__main__": ...`, so thats good. The second module doesnt define any functions. The moment you import that module, the code there will just run, aka a *side effect*. So if you were to stick that code into a function instead, you could import that function and call it on demand.